# Javascript code to press a particular button on a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an HTML form to upload two pictures separately (So I have two submit buttons) after selection automatically without the user having to press a submit button. From my research I'm supposed to use

this.form.submit();

The pictures will be saved in separate locations too.
I want to know how to target a particular button with either its name or id.

```
<input type = "file" name = "headshot1">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit1">

<input type = "file" name = "headshot2">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit2">
```

Then I have a php code to store the two pictures in two different places

Comment: Do you usse the jQuery framework or plain javascript?

Comment: plain javascript please

Comment: [Check this out.](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html)

Answer (score 1):

One way is by utilizing the `querySelector()` to get your object, and then chaining `addEventListener` off of it.

```
document.querySelector('button[name="myButton"]').addEventListener('click', function(){
    //stuff
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of a submit button too

Comment: @Eddy1011 Are you saying that you want to control the submission of the from when clicking on an element that is not in the form - say an `<a>` tag?

Comment: No! I wanna submit the form immediately the file is selected, so the user doesn't have to click a submit button. My problem is I have two files on the page to be stored in separate locations. I'm having a hard time writing a JS to submit the two file individually.

Comment: @Eddy1011 That's a completely different question. You're asking how to capture events when a file input is added and submit them independently. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly submit the form:

```
 document.getElementById("myFormId").submit();
```

If you still want to click the button go with:

```
 document.getElementById("buttonid").click();
```

Comment: The first won't be suitable because the files are to be saved in two different locations. I'm sorry I didn't mention that earlier, I just updated the question